# How can I create an arithmetic loop in a POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell-script, posix, bourne-shell

I know how to create an arithmetic `for` loop in `bash`.

How can one do an equivalent loop in a POSIX shell script?

As there are various ways of achieving the same goal, feel free to add your own answer and elaborate a little on how it works.

An example of one such `bash` loop follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i != 10; i++ ))
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have found useful information in [Shellcheck.net wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2039#arithmetic-for-loops), I quote:

1. Bash¹:

   ```
    for ((init; test; next)); do foo; done
   ```
2. POSIX:

   ```
    : "$((init))"
    while [ "$((test))" -ne 0 ]; do foo; : "$((next))"; done
   ```

though beware that `i++` is not POSIX so would have to be translated, for instance to `i += 1` or `i = i + 1`.

`:` is a null command that always has a successful exit code. `"$((expression))"` is an arithmetic expansion that is being passed as an argument to `:`. You can assign to variables or do arithmetic/comparisons in the arithmetic expansion.

---

So the above script in the question can be POSIX-wise re-written using those rules like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
: "$((i=1))"
while [ "$((i != 10))" -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "$i"
    : "$((i = i + 1))"
done
```

Though here, you can make it more legible with:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
while [ "$i" -ne 10 ]
do
    echo "$i"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

as in `init`, we're assigning a constant value, so we don't need to evaluate an arithmetic expression. The `i != 10` in `test` can easily be translated to a `[` expression, and for `next`, using a shell variable assignment as opposed to a variable assignment inside an arithmetic expression, lets us get rid of `:` and the need for quoting.

---

Beside `i++` -> `i = i + 1`, there are more translations of ksh/bash-specific constructs that are not POSIX that you might have to do:

- `i=1, j=2`. [The `,` arithmetic operator is not *really* POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1128) (and conflicts with the decimal separator in some locales with  ksh93). You could replace it with another operator like `+` as in `: "$(((i=1) + (j=2)))"` but using `i=1 j=2` would be a lot more legible.
- `a[0]=1`: no arrays in POSIX shells
- `i = 2**20`: no power operator in POSIX shell syntax. `<<` is supported though so for powers of two, one can use `i = 1 << 20`. For other powers, one can resort to `bc`: `i=$(echo "3 ^ 20" | bc)`
- `i = RANDOM % 3`: not POSIX. The closest in the POSIX toolchest is `i=$(awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(rand() * 3)}')`.

---

<sup>¹ technically, that syntax is from the ksh93 shell and is also available in zsh in addition to bash</sup>

Comment: Just a note about the _`test`_ condition: It is generally better not to check just against a single value (`10` in the example). Use `i < 10` instead of `i != 10`. Why? It is much more robust and logically correct. The condition will not stop working when you change the incrementation step, change the `i` value outside of the _`next`_ expression, when you use float instead of int (in other languages than shell) etc. --- BTW I am wondering if there are reasons to prefer one of these two variants of a numerical variable assignment: `: $((x = a + b))` or `x=$((a + b))`

Answer (score 5):

thanks for above in-depth background knowledge on the difference.  A drop in replacement that worked for me when using shellcheck.net was as below.

**BASH**

```
for i in {1..100}; do  
  ...  
done
```

**POSIX**

```
i=1; while [ $i -le 100 ]; do  
  ...  
  i=$(( i + 1 ))  
done
```

some people noted that seq is also an option using seq 1 10 . Creating a loop, however this is dependant that os has seq.

Comment: note that i have placed i=0 in the same line as while. although readability is not great, it is a one liner drop-in. This ensures that variable i is not tainted by anywhere else defined in the script.

Comment: The second code block should be `i=1` in order to be equivalent to the first code block.

Comment: Note that though not standard that `{1..100}` syntax is not specific to `bash`. It was actually copied from zsh.

Answer (score 2):

This method is even more general, since you can plug arbitrary `$` variable in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(seq 1 10); do
    echo $i
done
```

Just make sure, you have `seq` utility installed, but since it is in `CoreUtils`, you do.

Comment: Note that it cannot be used in contexts where `$IFS` may not contain the newline character or may contain decimal digits.